# Need to cast an object to unbounded wildcard....but how in my case?

Tags: java, unbounded-wildcard

```
public myConstuctor(Map<String, ?> myMap) {

    if (myMap.containsKey(MY_KEY)) {            

        myMap.put(MY_KEY, someObject);
    }

    someMemberVariable = new someClass(myMap);  
}
```

I am not able to put an object in the map due to the unbounded wildcard. I am not familiar with wildcard. What makes it difficult (for me..) is I am not able to change the constructor's input type (i.e. myMap) but I need to put an object in the map.

Will someone help..? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you believe the type of `someObject` is compatible with `myMap`,

```
((Map)myMap).put(k, v);
```

Comment: Yay! It works :) Thank you so much! Do you mind explaining why casting myMap to Map can get past the unbounded wildcard problem? I am hoping to really understand the solution instead of just making it work.. Isn't myMap always a Map? Thanks again!

Comment: oh, after more thoughts, I wonder if that's because when we don't specify the type of the key and the value, the type of them super-rides (is there such a  word..? :P) the unbound?

Comment: by casting it to "raw" type, we drop all generic type checking. back to the good old pre-generics days.